# fire function one time when element is created (pass to methods) / VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`. First I want to explain my code shortly:

I have a v-for with inputs, these I can create as often as I want with a `b-button -> addElement`. Or I can select an `item` from my `b-dropdown` - there I am checking the length of my selected and push the amount of my `arrayLength` as my inputs.

**->** e.g. selected array = ['1111', '2222', '3333'] -> arrayLength = 3 **->** 3 inputs

Now I need to get a function fired automatically (`marked as ???`) when exactly this case happend that I'm selecting something from my dropdown - e.g. is my `arrayLength = 3`, it should be fired 3 times with correct `id, indexParent and indexChild`. How can I solve that?

I need this above named `parameters` in my methods..

Thanks in advance!

```
<div v-for="(id, indexChild) in inputs" :key="indexChild">
  
  <b-dropdown text="Select" right variant="success">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="(item, indexDropdown) in json" :key="indexDropdown" @click="trySomething(item.Number)">{{item.Name}}</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>

  <b-button v-b-toggle="'newElement'+indexParent+indexChild">Element {{indexChild + 1}}></b-button>
  
  <b-collapse :id="'newElement'+indexParent+indexChild"
    <div ???="getValues(id, indexParent, indexChild)"> <!-- how can I fire this when created? -->
      <!-- Do some more code -->  
    </div>
  </b-collapse>
</div>


<!-- create new "item"-elements -->
<div>
  <b-button @click="addElement()">Add element</b-button>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
  addProduct() {
    this.inputs.push({})
  },

  trySomething(itemValue) {

    var array = [];
    const products = this.otherJSON.find((i) => i.Number === itemValue);
    for (let key in products.ID) {
      array.push(products.ID[key]);
    }
      
    this.getLengthArray = array.length;

    this.inputs.splice(0) //at first I need to delete all to push exact inputs based on arrayLength

    for (let i = 0; i < this.getLengthArray; i++) {
      this.inputs.push({});
    }
  },

  getValues(id, indexParent, indexChild) { //Here I need the parameters id, indexParent, indexChild
  }
},

data() {
  return {
    inputs: [{}],
  }
},

props: ["indexParent"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just used:

```
<div v-if="getValues(id, indexParent, indexChild)" v-once></div>
```

and it worked out for me!